# inserting an array

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following array that I want to insert into the table with the fields groupi_id, application_id and grant_id

the array is

```
array(
    'ApplicationsGrant' => array(
        'group_id' => array(
            (int) 0 => '72',
            (int) 1 => '72'
        ),
        'application_id' => array(
            (int) 0 => '1',
            (int) 1 => '2'
        ),
        'grant_id' => array(
            (int) 0 => 56,
            (int) 1 => 57
        )
    )
)
```

I want to insert the rows that every sub array goes with array key. so there will be 2 rows inserted in above case like this

insert into table (`group_id`. `application_id`, `grant_id`) Values (72, 1, 56);
insert into table (`group_id`. `application_id`, `grant_id`) Values (72, 2, 57);

howd I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Cake's Set::classicExtract() to pull out the values. I assume you know how to then save them to the DB.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html

In your case, something like (untested):

```
$result1 = Set::classicExtract($a, '{n}.{s}.{s}.0');
$result2 = Set::classicExtract($a, '{n}.{s}.{s}.1');
```

If you need the keys, you can extract those first:

```
$fields = Set::classicExtract($a, '{n}.{s}.{s}');
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried this one

```
    $d = array(
        'ApplicationsGrant' => array(
            'group_id' => array(
                (int) 0 => '72',
                (int) 1 => '72'
            ),
            'application_id' => array(
                (int) 0 => '1',
                (int) 1 => '2'
            ),
            'grant_id' => array(
                (int) 0 => 56,
                (int) 1 => 57
            )
        )
    );
    for ($i=0; $i<count($d['ApplicationsGrant']['group_id']); $i++) {
        echo $d['ApplicationsGrant']['group_id'][$i]."<br/>"; //outputs 72, 72
    }
```